# Keep iTunes library in sync on OS X and Boot Camp (Windows 8)?

Tags: itunes, macos, network, bootcamp, windows

Is it possible for me to keep my iTunes libraries in sync with each other on OS X and Windows if so how? My iTunes library is stored on a network share made available via AFP and SMB. Is it possible for me to make it so that any changes made on iTunes on Windows are also shown in OS X and vice-versa or will I have to maintain separate iTunes Libraries resulting in a clunky mess (especially when iTunes Match starts uploading playlists twice and other things)?

Answer (score 1):

*Later edit*
See [iTunes: Moving iTunes Files (Self Managed)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163594/itunes-moving-itunes-files-self-managed/163601#163601) for a better explanation of how to achieve dual, almost-in-sync libraries across different machines

---

[This is not a hugely technical explanation, more one of the frustration I've had doing the same thing... if you want more details, ask...]

You can share the file location, but both machines will 'see' it differently. iTunes uses absolute references [truly irritatingly] so the only way to keep the Library in sync is to either add the same files to both [not good if it's supposed to be self-organising] or to manually copy the iTunes Library.xml file & use BBEdit to change the path structure for every entry - which can be done but then may take the Windows version of iTunes up to 10 hours to process it.

Comment: "which can be done but then may take the Windows version of iTunes up to 10 hours to process it." - No disrespect to Apple but the OS X version of iTunes is just as clunky :(. Where is the iTunes Library.xml file stored, is it in some temporary / hidden directory?

Comment: it's in 'Music' ... ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.xml  & yes, I'm pretty sure many of us wish the paths were relative ;-)